# how to name an EC2 EBS volume in AWS console?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

How can I name my Amazon EC2 EBS volumes using the AWS Console? By default the name field is empty, and I can see no option to edit this, unlike the actual EC2 instance.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The "name" field ist just a tag. To edit this, klick on your EBS volume, go to "Tags" in the lower panel and you will already find a tag "Name" there. Fill in your desired name as the value and it will also show up in the overview panel.

Answer (score 8):

The "Name" that shows up in the AWS console is just a tag. This applies to AMIs, volumes, instances, etc..

You can change it from the command line using ec2-api-tools with following command:

```
ec2addtag <entity_id> --tag Name=<name>
```

You can install ec2-api-tools (Ubuntu) by calling:

```
sudo apt-get install ec2-api-tools
```